# Why don't Shift+arrow bindings work in clojure-mode in emacs terminal?

Tags: macos, emacs, clojure

If I runs emacs in  a terminal (i.e start emacs in iTerm2 with `emacs -nw`)
using `windmove` and it's default bindings, I should be able to navigate between windows using various combinations of `Shift` + `→` `←` `↑` `↓`, Also `paredit` has bindings that involve `Ctrl`/`Meta` + `→` `←` `↑` `↓`, these all work fine in (say) an elisp mode buffer.

Looks like the arrow keys functionality relies on emacs decoding terminal escape sequences, via (I think) the `input-decode-map`

However, if I set the major mode as `clojure-mode` then the decoding of the escape sequences appears to be disabled (or overwritten). When I execute those bindings I just get the escape sequence instead.

What's going on with the bindings in `clojure-mode` ?

Versions:

- emacs 24.3.1 (have tried maxosxforemacs.com version and homebrew)
- clojure-mode 20131117.2306 (have tried other versions)
- OSX 10.8.5
- iTerm2 1.0.0.20131124

(disclaimer: [I raised this as an issue on clojure-mode, but no solution is forthcoming](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode/issues/190))

**UPDATE 2013/12/10:** To be absolutely clear: this problem is specific to `clojure-mode`. `emacs -nw` in iTerm + arrow keys works fine in other major modes. I'm sure I'm doing something silly that is causing this, I'd like to know what.

Comment: What do you mean by emacs terminal? emacs in a terminal? which emulator if so? M-x describe-key will tell you what function is using a given binding (and will tell you what keypress emacs is getting, in case it is an issue of input conversion lossage).

Comment: Looking at your other post above, I imagine the difference could come down to incompatibility between iterm and xterm. Try running emacs inside screen or tmux, they intercept input events and are sometimes better at being compatible than the terminal itself.

Comment: @noisesmith everything works fine in modes other than ``clojure-mode``, in ``clojure-mode``, ``M-x describe-key`` simply describes the first meaningful character in the escape sequence (usually [), so the issue is something specific to ``clojure-mode``

Answer (score 2):

Almost identical setup here, but no similar problem. Here's what I would do anyway. First, evaluate the following emacs-lisp code in the scratch buffer.

```el
(progn
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2D" [S-left])  
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-[ 1 ; 2 C") [S-right])  
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-[ 1 ; 2 B")[S-down])  
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2A" [S-up])  
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;6A" [S-C-up])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;6B" [S-C-down]))
```

Try the windmove bindings when clojure-mode is activated. If this fixes your problem, and assuming your TERM environment variable is set to `xterm-256color`, put the following in your `init.el`

```el
(if (equal "xterm-256color" (tty-type)) 
(progn
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2D" [S-left])  
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-[ 1 ; 2 C") [S-right])  
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-[ 1 ; 2 B")[S-down])  
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2A" [S-up])  
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;6A" [S-C-up])
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;6B" [S-C-down])))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check your settings in Iterm, more specifically the "Global shortcut keys". Those will take precedence over what is sent to emacs. C-Shift-Arrow is used to switch tabs in Iterm I believe and may be interfering with emacs.

Comment: @sw1nn says it is only a problem in clojure-mode. It works fine in other modes.